# What would cause a high `%wa` value when there is nothing performing heavy io?

Tags: linux, top, io

I have a `92.3%wa` value on `top` right now under linux and when I run `iotop -a`, I see nothing causing heavy io. What might be the cause of the large `%wa` value and how can I go about diagnosing this?

The entire header portion of `top` is:

```
top - 09:23:46 up 126 days, 11:09, 57 users,  load average: 1.00, 1.00, 1.00
Tasks: 480 total,   1 running, 467 sleeping,  11 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  2.5%us,  2.5%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 95.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2055868k total,  1682968k used,   372900k free,    21928k buffers
Swap:  4194296k total,  1550828k used,  2643468k free,   562400k cached
```

Comment: Might help if you show the rest of the top info (the header portion at least).

Answer (score 1):

Your system is already swapping quite a bit (~1.5G), which *might* explain a high I/O not showing in netio: it's not a regular process doing it.

It's also possible to have primarily a single process doing IO (while most of the others are inactive/sleeing). That single active process will influence the overall CPU usage **percentages** (like `%wa`) more than the others since it will be scheduled much more often than the others. It doesn't have to be a large amount of I/O (enough to pinpoint it in netio), could be just a relatively small one, but with a very small FS cache hit rate, thus forced to wait a lot for the actual disk head movements.

For example a `find` or a `ls -laR` on a big partition (from a slower disk) largely filled and with a complex/deep directory structure will likely display such behaviour. The fragmentation will matter a lot, too.

Comment: It *is* the swapping.